# Cannot find the tree conflicted files after merge

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, tree-conflict

I was trying to merge from one branch(B1) to another(B2). I have followed the given steps:

`Right click on the folder -> Merge... -> Merge two different trees -> From B1 to B2 (HEAD Revision) -> Merge(checked Compare white spaces option by default)`

Merge finished with tree conflicts.

The issue is I am not able to find any of the conflicted files inside my folder. But the folder is having the conflict mark on it. Is there anything wrong in the above steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must not** use "Merge two different trees" in order to merge B1 to B2. "Merge two different trees" merges A+B into (unrelated to A||B) C node

Comment: Then what is the best option to Merge from one branch to another?  `Merge a range of revisions` or `Reintegrate a branch`

Answer (score 3):

you should use `svn status` for reviewing the tree conflict. On treeconflicts the last line gives you the exakct information you need.

A tree conflict means 1 side deleted/removed a file while the other side modified its content. In 1 situation there is no "conflict file", because if you deleted/renamed the local file there is no file for conflicting.
See both variants:

1st : **Remote:modified; local: deleted**

you got a tree conflict saying:

> local file moved away, incoming file edit upon update

and you can either `svn revert` your deletion or keep the deletion(nothing to be done)
After you decided, just use `svn resolve` and commit

2nd : **Remote:deleted; local:modified**
you got a tree conflict again, this time saying:

> local file edit, incoming file delete upon update

If you `svn revert` your local modification now, keep in mind that svn will **delete the file** as it was renamed already. This also solves the treeconflict implicit. You can also delete the renamed file and say `svn resolve [local_file]` this keeping your file as new add in your working copy

The same goes for folders, however there are more files affected, but the basic principle is still the same.

Comment: So the option before me here is to `svn revert` the conflicted(deleted) files. Right?